# FUSE filesystem on Mac (osxfuse) - how to tell OS I don't support exteneded attributes and forks?

Tags: macos, filesystems, fuse, macfuse

Is there any option to set on init that my filesystem doesn't support resource forks and extended attributes? So that I don't get bombarded with getattr for "._*" files requests, as well as getxattr/setxattr requests for all files?
Also, is there any way to "tell" a filesystem that my FS is case-sensitive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out there are 2 options - noapplexattr and noappledouble - which can be used just for that. Here's the link: https://code.google.com/p/macfuse/wiki/OPTIONS.